# $(C + \bar{A})(AB + AB\bar{C})$ Simplifying Boolean

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, formal-proofs

Basically I have this terrible teacher that only gave us a ton of different examples using DeMorgran's Law, and now that one of these can't be solved using DeMorgan's Law, I am pretty lost on what to do. The whole question is below, the problem is that the only rule he has shown us is DeMorgan's Law...

Use the Boolean Logic rules provided to simplify the following expression.
$(C + \bar{A})(AB + AB\bar{C})$.

Comment: The distributive law works... What happens to terms with $A\bar{A}$ or $C\bar{C}$ in them?

Comment: Would you do it the same way you would do a regular math problem such as (4 * 8)(3 *4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(C+\overline{A})(AB+ABC')&=ABC+ABC\overline{C}+A\overline{A}B+\overline{A}AB\overline{C}\\&=ABC+AB\varnothing +\varnothing B+\varnothing B\overline{C}\\&=ABC\end{align}

Comment: I can see you did distribution for the first step, and then letters canceled in the second step, but how does that second line become just ABC?

Comment: I think I got it, is it because the letters cancel in the last 3 terms and create a 0, so then they all multiply to 0?

Comment: Yes. However, in the terminology of sets we dont refert to it as $0$ but $\varnothing$ (empty set or nothing)

Comment: @msm This isn't sets though, it's boolean algebra. Usually the bottom is referred to as $0$ or $\bot$ in this context. (It's more likely to be $0$ in this case since OP is using $+$ and $\cdot$ notation instead of $\land$ and $\lor$.)

Answer (score 1):

$$(C+A')(AB+ABC')$$
$$=(C+A')AB(1+C')$$

As $1+C'=C$ in $GF(2)$,

$$=(C+A')ABC$$
$$=CABC+A'ABC$$

As $A'A=0$ and $CC=C$ in $GF(2)$,

$$=ABC$$